# Window close not working on react js app, How to close current tab on browser onclick back button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

Want to detect user on last tab and then if user click back button browser need to close.

I've tried this.

```
         window.onpopstate = e=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            if(e.state==null){
                let win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
                     win.close();    
            }
        }
```

above code opening new tab but not closing current tab.

Note this error too.
"Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."

Comment: I can't replicate your error. Running just the code inside the if statement opens and closes a tab successfully.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention its not working on mobile browser. @evolutionxbox

Comment: Which mobile browser? there are many

Comment: its not working on mobile browser Google Chrome.there both tab seen current tab and blank tab @evolutionxbox